# Using radio box selection to display multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, php, css, radio-button

I need to be able to use three radio buttons to determine which P's display on a page.
All items are queried from a database so there is no fixed number.  I'd like to stick with javascript if possible.  All is written inside PHP code

Tried using the following:

```
        <?php
        //Javascript function to show selected duration price:
        echo"<script>
        function showPrice(duration)
        {
            if(duration == \"1\")
            {
                var a = document.querySelectorAll('p[id^=price1]')
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index)
                {
                    document.getElementById(a[index]).style.display=\"block;\";
                }



            }
            else
            {
                var a = document.querySelectorAll('p[id^=price1]')
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index)
                {
                    document.getElementById(a[index]).style.display=\"none;\";

                }

            }
            if(duration == \"2\")
            {
                var a = document.querySelectorAll('p[id^=price2]')
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index)
                {
                    document.getElementById(a[index]).style.display=\"block;\";

                }

            }
            else
            {
                var a = document.querySelectorAll('p[id^=price2]')
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index)
                {
                    document.getElementById(a[index]).style.display=\"none;\";

                }

            }
            if(duration == \"3\")
            {
                var a = document.querySelectorAll('p[id^=price3]')
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index)
                {
                    document.getElementById(a[index]).style.display=\"block;\";

                }

            }
            else
            {
                var a = document.querySelectorAll('p[id^=price3]')
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index)
                {
                    document.getElementById(a[index]).style.display=\"none;\";

                }

            }

        }
        </script>
        ";
```

Then each P will have the option of 6 prices that should only be visible if the corresponding radio options are selected:

```
    while($pack_row = mysql_fetch_array($packageResults))
    {
        echo"<div class=submenuContainer style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px $leftMargin"."px; width: $product_params[linkContainerWidth]"."px;\">";
        echo"\n\n\n <a class=submenu title=\"{$pack_row["package_name"]}\" id='package_id' href=\"javascript:ajaxFunction({$pack_row["package_id"]},null);inPagePopup();\" style=\"background-image: url('$link_bg_img');  height: $product_params[link_height]"."px; width: $product_params[link_width]"."px; \">";
        echo"\n</a>";
        echo"\n<span class=submenuExtraText>";
        $pricesAry = price_calculator("{$pack_row["package_id"]}","","","");
        echo"\n <p style=\"float: left; text-align: left;\"><input class=\"$radioInputStyle\" type=radio name=leaseInfo[packageID] value={$pack_row["package_id"]}> SELECT</p>";

    //P's hidden unless lease duration selected below
        echo"\n <p class='priceDisplay' id='price1".$ck."' style=\"float: right; text-align: right; display: none;\"><b>\$".$pricesAry['subTotal'][1]."</b></p>";
        echo"\n <p class='priceDisplay' id='price2".$ck."' style=\"float: right; text-align: right; display: none;\"><b>\$".$pricesAry['subTotal'][2]."</b></p>";
        echo"\n <p class='priceDisplay' id='price3".$ck."' style=\"float: right; text-align: right; display: none;\"><b>\$".$pricesAry['subTotal'][3]."</b></p>";
        echo"\n <p class='priceDisplay' id='price4".$ck."' style=\"float: right; text-align: right; display: none;\"><b>\$".$pricesAry['subTotal'][4]."</b></p>";
        echo"\n <p class='priceDisplay' id='price5".$ck."' style=\"float: right; text-align: right; display: none;\"><b>\$".$pricesAry['subTotal'][5]."</b></p>";
        echo"\n <p class='priceDisplay' id='price6".$ck."' style=\"float: right; text-align: right; display: none;\"><b>\$".$pricesAry['subTotal'][6]."</b></p>";
        echo"\n</span>"; 
        echo"\n</div>";
        $ck++;
        $t++;
    }
```

And here are the radio boxes:

```
        echo"<b>How long?</b><br>";
        echo"<input id=duration1 class=radio type=radio name=leaseInfo[duration] value=\"1\" onClick=\"showPrice(1);\"> 3  &#160&#160&#160&#160";  
        echo"<input id=duration2 class=radio type=radio name=leaseInfo[duration] value=\"2\" onClick=\"showPrice(2);\" checked> 6  &#160&#160&#160&#160";
        echo"<input id=duration3 class=radio type=radio name=leaseInfo[duration] value=\"3\" onClick=\"showPrice(3);\"> 12  &#160&#160&#160&#160";
        echo"<br><br>";


?>
```

Comment: The PHP is really irrelevant here. Just post the rendered output and your JavaScript.

Comment: Then I'll need to remove all the variables that populate various fields.  I thought it might be relevant for those replying to know the data/page is dynamic and not static HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTbNz/9/)

```
function showPrice(duration) {
    var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('priceDisplay');
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        var price = prices[i];
        if (price.classList.contains('p'+ duration))
            price.style.display = "block";
        else
            price.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```
<input id=duration1 class=radio type=radio name=leaseInfo[duration] value="1" onClick="showPrice(1)" checked><label for=duration1> Price 1</label>
<input id=duration2 class=radio type=radio name=leaseInfo[duration] value="2" onClick="showPrice(2)"><label for=duration2> Price 2</label>
<input id=duration3 class=radio type=radio name=leaseInfo[duration] value="3" onClick="showPrice(3)"><label for=duration3> Price 3</label>

<h3>Item 1</h3>
<p class='priceDisplay p1' id='price1-i1'><b>Price1: $35.45</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p2' id='price2-i1' style='display: none;'><b>Price2: $22.45</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p3' id='price3-i1' style='display: none;'><b>Price3: $654.45</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p4' id='price4-i1' style='display: none;'><b>Price4: $11.45</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p5' id='price5-i1' style='display: none;'><b>Price5: $5.45</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p6' id='price6-i1' style='display: none;'><b>Price6: $77.45</b></p>

<h3>Item 2</h3>
<p class='priceDisplay p1' id='price1-i2'><b>Price1: $45.65</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p2' id='price2-i2' style='display: none;'><b>Price2: $12.45</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p3' id='price3-i2' style='display: none;'><b>Price3: $14.35</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p4' id='price4-i2' style='display: none;'><b>Price4: $32.46</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p5' id='price5-i2' style='display: none;'><b>Price5: $45.52</b></p>
<p class='priceDisplay p6' id='price6-i2' style='display: none;'><b>Price6: $99.76</b></p>
```

Comment: I think I tried something similar.  The problem I ran into is there are numerous items listed,  each with potential for 6 different prices.  So a given page may have 25 products each with 6 possible lease durations.  Not sure if I'm explaining that well?!

Comment: I just tried it minus the LABEL part, and it didn't work. FireFox console shows:  TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: As far as the code you've posted, all I can infer is you have a collection of prices, with unique identifiers spanning from price1 and up. If you can post a better example of what the end result should look like, it'd help to get a better idea. As for your error, the code works fine in JSFiddle so it's certainly functioning. Something must have went wrong with how you implemented it on your end.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I'm sure its the way I'm implementing it.  I edited the post to show the iteration process for each product.  I added the foreach loop to demonstrate how the 6 prices are attached to each product...and there can be countless products per page.

Comment: Hmm, so if there are 6 possible lease durations per item, why only 3 radio buttons? Also, is there only a single set of radio buttons total for all items, or one radio set per item?

Comment: Ha!  Good observation.  I designed it with the ability to expand in the future.  For now there are only 3 lease options but 6 price fields in the database.  There is only one set of radio buttons for the lease duration - there are other radio buttons I omitted as they aren't pertinent - those are evaluated server side for the next page.

Comment: Update:  so if I omit the php variable $ck, then the script works but only for the first product.  I'm assuming because prices attached to consecutive products share the same ID's as the first product now.  The variable $ck simply adds the iteration value to the ID value, e.g. price1$ck might be price12 depending on the number of loops PHP 'while' has made.

Comment: I've updated my answer (and JSFiddle) in hopes I've gotten a better grasp on what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks,  but I'm not seeing anything different in the above code?  I added the post compile source so you can get a better picture of whats going on after PHP sends out the page.

Comment: Should I be looking a the code directly above these comments or the code at the very top?

Comment: My code as it is now, which you edited over before looking at the changes.

Comment: Appears to be working!  Thanks a bunch!  Is there a way for it to default to a duration that is set "checked"?  It appears to be showing the duration 1 even though duration 2 is set 'checked' by default?

Comment: In my example, I set the first to be checked by default. If you want the second to be the default, just set the checked attribute to the second radio button instead and remove `display:none` from the appropriate <p> tags.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks again!  Let me know if theres anything I can do to return the favor.